# Anaconda Nested Virtual environment bug

Tags: python, bash, terminal, anaconda

Whenever I open terminal using VS code, it shows nested conda environment. Currently there are two environments, base and myenv. When I start terminal, I am greeted by this :

```
(myenv) (base) username:directory$
```

Any tips on how to debug this or how to find out what's going on?

Comment: I have seen this when you have a python venv and a conda env active. is `myenv` also a conda env?

Comment: Yes myenv is a conda environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into a similar situation, and it only occurs in vscode's embedded terminal, which feels like a vscode bug.
And it shows two environments but doesn't really affect the actual use. If you only want to show one environment, you can run the command `conda config --set auto_activate_base False` to set the base environment to not be automatically activated.